# Overloading function differs in number & type of parameters in Typescript using Union types

Tags: javascript, oop, typescript, overloading, union-types

I'm trying to overload a function which has two overloads like below

```
getData(): MyModel
getData<T>(type:string):T
```

Now based on the details found in the [blog](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/08/18/function-overloads-in-typescript) , I'm trying to use `union types` to provide the types of parameters the above functions can take.

**Case 1:** (No problems here)

When functions have parameters and they differ only in types like below

```
getData(type:number): MyModel
getData<T>(type:string):T
getData<T>(type: number|string): MyModel:T {
 //implementation
}
```

**Case 2:** (Problem: How to use Union type in this case)

When functions parameters differ in number and types both like below

```
getData(): MyModel
getData<T>(type:string):T
```

**Questions**

1. How to use `Union types` in `Case 2`
2. If `Union types` cannot be used than how to overload these functions(using Typescript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the parameter as optional and use a union type for the return type:

```
class MyClass {
    getData(): MyModel;
    getData<T>(type: string): T;
    getData<T>(type?: string): MyModel | T {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20MyModel%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getData()%3A%20MyModel%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getData%3CT%3E(type%3A%20string)%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getData%3CT%3E(type%3F%3A%20string)%3A%20MyModel%20%7C%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20null%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D))

Comment: But its not showing the two overloads separately in the intellisence like it is mentioned in the blog (https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/08/18/function-overloads-in-typescript)

Comment: It does in playground. Must be something in your ide.